# External team partial access to Azure Data Lake

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake-gen2

Our team has an Azure Data Lake Gen2. Another team would like to input data to the Data Lake but they should not be able to view our contents in the Data Lake. How can I achieve it?

I think partial access is not possible and need to create another Azure Data Lake for the external team to put data. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-access-control). You can add RBAC access to the data lake, so you can create a new folder where external team has write permissions and no permissions to other folders.

Another option is to create a different container in the storage account and configure IAM control access.